# Using apply functions in SparkR

Tags: sparkr

I am currently trying to implement some functions using sparkR version 1.5.1. I have seen older (version 1.3) examples, where people used the apply function on DataFrames, but it looks like this is no longer directly available. Example:

```
x = c(1,2)
xDF_R = data.frame(x)
colnames(xDF_R) = c("number")
xDF_S = createDataFrame(sqlContext,xDF_R)
```

Now, I can use the function sapply on the data.frame object

```
xDF_R$result = sapply(xDF_R$number, ppois, q=10)
```

When I use a similar logic on the DataFrame

```
xDF_S$result = sapply(xDF_S$number, ppois, q=10)
```

I get the error message "Error in as.list.default(X) : 
  no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector"

Can I somehow do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with [user defined functions in Spark 2.0](http://people.apache.org/~pwendell/spark-releases/spark-2.0.0-rc4-docs-updated/sparkr.html#applying-user-defined-function).

```
wrapper = function(df){
+     out = df
+     out$result = sapply(df$number, ppois, q=10)
+     return(out)
+ }
> xDF_S2 = dapplyCollect(xDF_S, wrapper)
> identical(xDF_S2, xDF_R)
[1] TRUE
```

Note you need a wrapper function like this because you can't pass the extra arguments in directly, but that may change in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The native R functions do not support Spark DataFrames. We can use [user defined functions in SparkR](https://databricks.com/blog/2018/08/15/100x-faster-bridge-between-spark-and-r-with-user-defined-functions-on-databricks.html) to execute native R modules. These are executed on the executors and thus the libraries must be available on all the executors.

For example, suppose we have a custom function `holt_forecast` which takes in a data.table as an argument.

Sample R code

```
sales_R_df %>%
  group_by(product_id) %>%
  do(holt_forecast(data.table(.))) %>%
  data.table(.) -> dt_holt
```

For using UDFs, we need to specify the schema of the output data.frame returned by the execution of the native R method. This schema is used by Spark to generate back the Spark DataFrame.

Equivalent SparkR code

1. Define the schema

   ```
     structField("product_id", "integer"),
     structField("audit_date", "date"),
     structField("holt_unit_forecast", "double"),
     structField("holt_unit_forecast_std", "double")
   )
   ```
2. Execute the method

   ```
     library(data.table)
     library(lubridate)
     library(dplyr)
     library(forecast)
     sales <- data.table(x)
     y <- data.frame(key,holt_forecast(sales))
   }, dt_holt_schema)
   ```

Reference: https://shbhmrzd.medium.com/stl-and-holt-from-r-to-sparkr-1815bacfe1cc